# I can't install AutoDockTools 1.5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I tried executing command 'source install.sh' and the Terminal install the AutoDockTools packages. However at the end of it, bash denied permission to the directory.

[image: source install.sh command]
[image: permission denied]

I still can run AutoDockTools using command 'adt' in the same terminal. However, when I closed the terminal and open it again, the AutoDockTools packages are not installed and I have to execute the command 'source install.sh' to install it again. How can I permanently install the package and does the problem has to do with bash giving privileges?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to http://mgltools.scripps.edu/downloads and click on mgltools_Linux-x86_64_1.5.6_Install this will download mgltools_Linux-x86_64_1.5.6_Install and the later goes on download folder.
2. To grant execute permission, type the following command at a command prompt:

   ```
       chmod +x MGLTools-$Version-Linux-x86-Install 
       but change it depend on your download folder in my case:
       chmod +x /home/suhad/Downloads/mgltools_Linux-x86_64_1.5.6_Install
   ```
3. Type :
   sudo /home/suhad/Downloads/mgltools_Linux-x86_64_1.5.6_Install
   Press Enter.

   The wizard for installation begin follow the wizard instruction and choose the destination location where you want to install mgltools after finishing the wizard go to the destination location and launch the  mgltools_Linux-x86_64_1.5.6 icon the autodock tools will start.
   you can type in the first icon on the top left of ubuntu14.04 for search your computer or online resource :

type : adt
the icon appear and the tools launched.

**Remember that without sudo you cann't install because it permit the access and without it you get permission denied.

Comment: thank you very much suhad. it has been very helpful. however, how do i set path to autodocktools permanently (meaning when i turn on my pc, i can just typed in adt in the terminal, and adt will launch straight away)? i haven't find a solution to that yet as i have to open the README files and have to paste the path set for bash shell every time i open a new session of terminal for me to launch adt.